# Why was Cunningham Sr. taken aback when Scout talks to him about entailment?

Tags: plot-explanation, to-kill-a-mockingbird

In the movie *To Kill a Mockingbird*, when the angry crowd reached the police-station to hurt **Tom Robinson**, they found **Atticus Finch** already sitting outside the door blocking their way.

After a few moments, Atticus' daughter **Scout** (alongwith her brother and friend) came from behind the crowd and suddenly and innocently starts talking to **Cunningham Sr.**, from the crowd, about his entailment issues.

I understand that this conversation changed the ongoing subject rather awkwardly which might catch the crowd off guard but why did this normal, harmless dialogue made **Cunningham Sr.** (and to some extent even the crowd) a little ashamed, eventually making the crowd to leave in peace?

Comment: Related: https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/9169/what-does-entailment-mean-in-to-kill-a-mockingbird

Comment: ["So, in the jail house scene, Scout is just asking how it's getting along in payment. Because of Scout's sweet nature, Mr Cunningham suddenly feels shameful about being part of the lynch mob and gets them all to leave with him."](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0056592/faq)

Comment: https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-does-this-quote-mean-hey-mr-cunningham-how-s-305916